# In Blender 3.5.0 how can you reverse the colour of the Voronoi Texture Distance output using math nodes?

Tags: texturing, procedural

In Blender 3.5.0 how can you reverse the colour of the Voronoi Texture Distance output using math nodes? The current output is black centre, white edges; I'd like white centre, black edges. Please don't suggest ColorRamp with swopped handles. Id like to do this with math nodes.

Comment: did u try just subtract? so math node (1 - distance)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this node setup:

[image]

[image]

i am not totally sure whether 1 is the maximum of voronoi distance - you might have to play with that value - but that's how you can invert it.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks great suggestion. But, yes, I'm also not sure what the range is that the distance socket outputs (0>1? Maybe -1>0>1?) I'm using the Moroni to drive displacement and when I input the pure Distance socket output into the height I get vastly different results to when I do the same using the ColorRamp on the noodle to swop colours, which I'm convinced is normalising the output.

Comment: @JKCapeTown The _Distance_ output gives no values below 0 since the Euclidian distance can never be negative. It can be above 1 though, you can easily check this by using a _Math_ node set to _Greater Than_ with 1 as threshold. However, in the screenshot above you can see the new _Voronoi Texture_ node which comes with version 4.0, there you can check the _Normalize_ option which will map the values to the 0 to 1 range.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: didn't know that - learnt again something from you ;)

Comment: @Chris You're welcome. Additionally I must say that using _Normalize_ although limiting the values also makes the result much less contrasted, the values don't seem to go down to 0. So I would rather use a _Map Range_ node and try to adjust the _Min/Max_ values so that they span over the complete range.

Comment: @JKCapeTown I forgot to mention: no, a _Color Ramp_ is not normalizing the values. Normalizing is mapping the minimum and maximum values to a range of 0 to 1. The _Color Ramp_ is cropping the input values to the 0 to 1 range. So if you plug in something that goes from -5 to 15, the _Color Ramp_ crops it to 0 to 1, so -5 to 0 get the color which is at the left end, and 1 to 15 get the color at the right end.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. So what would you do to invert the Distance output of the Voronoi texture node to keep the 'integrity' of the numbers intact?

Comment: I'd like to have the full 'uncropped' range swapped around (a pure inversion), so I suppose your last instruction is how I should do that. Could you post a screengrab of how you would do it - just so I can be sure I'm implementing is right (sometimes I misinterpret written answers). Thanks v much.

Comment: @JKCapeTown I would use a _Map Range_ node. However the problem is, the maximum distance is hard to determine because depending on the Voronoi pattern, the scale etc. it is hard to tell how much the maximum distance will be. It can even be that there is no value above 1. The question is: do you need them exactly from 0 to 1? Or do you just want to make sure they stay in this range without being cropped? Then you should use a _Map Range_ with _From Min_ = 0, _From Max_ = Sqrt(2) and _To Min_ = 1 and _To Max_ = 0 (swapping min/max on output so there is no subtraction necessary).

Comment: @JKCapeTown There you go: [vector normalizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUVlG.jpg), this is basically what the _Normalize_ option in Blender 4.0 does. But I'm sorry, there was a mistake in my other comment, the _From Max_ value has to be Sqrt(3), because the _Voronoi Texture_ is set to 3D. If it was set to 2D it would have been Sqrt(2). You lose a lot of contrast there but you can be sure to not lose any values through cropping.

Comment: Thank you Gordon - it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a (not so) short explanation/visualization in what range the *Distance* output of a *Voronoi Texture* set to *Euclidian* can result. The node generates random points (unless *Random* is set to 0) in 1, 2 or 3 dimensions which have a maximum distance of 1 per dimension (4D is like 3-dimensional with *W* working like a seed value).

**1D:** The output will be a single random value in $[0,1]$ (to get different values you can change *W* as seed).

**2D:** The output values are in $[0,\sqrt{2}]$ with each point lying in the plane, i.e. each "cell" has a black center with value 0.

**3D:** The output values are in $[0,\sqrt{3}]$, the point can lie above or below the plane, i.e. the center of "cells" can be brighter than black.

The reason for the maximum values of $\sqrt{2}$ for 2D and $\sqrt{3}$ for 3D comes from the formula for the Euclidian distance $d$ between two points $p$ and $q$ given through their coordinates $p=(p_1,...,p_n)$ and $q=(q_1,...,q_n)$:

$$d(p,q) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (q_i-p_i)^2} = \sqrt{(q_1 - p_1)^2 + \cdots + (q_n - p_n)^2}.$$

For a 2D texture this means

$$d_{2D}(p,q) = \sqrt{(q_1 - p_1)^2 + (q_2 - p_2)^2}$$

and a 3D texture

$$d_{3D}(p,q) = \sqrt{(q_1 - p_1)^2 + (q_2 - p_2)^2 + (q_3 - p_3)^2}.$$

Since the node generates points with a maximum distance of 1 for each difference $|q_i-p_i|$, the maximum distance $max(d)$ two points $p$, $q$ in 2D or 3Dcan have from each other is

$$max(d_{2D}) = \sqrt{1 + 1} = \sqrt{2}$$
or
$$max(d_{3D}) = \sqrt{1 + 1 + 1} = \sqrt{3}.$$

To visualize that, here a simple illustration of these maximum distances two points can have in the 2D and 3D *Voronoi Texture* node:

[image: voronoi point distances]

Last quick note: regarding the minimum value of 0 and why there are no negative output values: physically nothing can be closer than distance 0, and mathematically each squared subtraction $(q_i-p_i)^2$ will always give a value $\geq 0$, therefore the square root of the sum is $\geq 0$ as well.